# How to add a <remove /> block using Remove-WebConfigurationProperty to a web.config?

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to add a `<remove />` key to a web.config to remove the WebDAV module.  Currently the configuration for the web.config is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>  
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Server.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

... and I would like to update it programmatically using PowerShell to the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>    
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Server.Host.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to use the PowerShell IIS module Remove-WebConfigurationProperty, but I can't get it to add the block.

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/webapp'  -Filter "system.webServer/modules" -Name "WebDAVModule" -Location "."
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `-Location` to control that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/remove-webconfigurationproperty?view=win10-ps

Comment: Thanks @LexLi.  I tried that and referenced the command I was using above which includes the -Location property.  It's possible that I'm using it incorrectly.  Open to suggestions.

Comment: When passing a location to cmdlet, you should to use things like `Default Web Site/webapp`, not `.`.

Comment: Can't you just update the xml by creating the `<modules>` element and append that to `configuration.location.'system.webServer'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Theo, that was a good suggestion.  I used the following PowerShell script to update the web.config.

```
$PathWebConfig = "C:\web.config";
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content($PathWebConfig);
$Node = $xmlDoc.configuration.location.'system.webServer'.modules;

if ($Node -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Node doesn't exist.";
    $xmlNodeModules = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element","modules","");
    $xmlKeyRemove = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element","remove","");
    $xmlKeyRemove.SetAttribute("name","WebDAVModule");
    $xmlNodeModules.AppendChild($xmlKeyRemove) | Out-Null;
    $xmlDoc.configuration.location.'system.webServer'.AppendChild($xmlNodeModules) | Out-Null;
    $xmlDoc.save($PathWebConfig);
} else {
    Write-Host "Node exists.";

}
```